# best way to create a string array through macro

Tags: c

I am trying to crate a parametric static array in a header file.
Let me elaborate my requirement

Wanted to create below array in header file statically which can be resolved at 
compile time

```
static char test_array[][256] = {   
                              "hello_1",
                              "hello_2",
                              "hello_3" };
```

I need to generate this using macro  which can do substitution with %d for 1,2 and 3 and the number 
of parameter also not fixed. What I mean here is tomorrow this array I can simply change through header file to

```
static char test_array[][256] = {
                          "hello_1",
                          "hello_45",
                          "hello_39",
                          "hello_101" };
```

I have the code to do it at run time in .c file but specifically I want to do it in a header file through macros .

Comment: How do you expect to call the macro? Can you give an example? Maybe you need something else, not a syntax trick, but a tool that does this.

Comment: basically my aim is to create the array at compile time and I will simple use to pass the array to some function which will fetch some parameters based on the array

Comment: It is not good to define data in header file. But you can make a .c file with that, which can be included in another .c file. I don't see why you need a macro. If tomorrow will be different from yesterday or the day after, is the solution to have a dynamic array whose values are initialised from a file at run time?

Comment: The reason I ma saying it to be in macro is   based on the #define my parameters will be different  example #define a array will have two parameters and for #define b array will have three parameters

Comment: For compile-time generation of arrays like interpolation tables of sensors I sometime use [COG](https://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/)

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to write generator, that generates header array in compile time. A short time ago I wrote program that may point you the right direction:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2018 Krzysztof "Palaiologos" Szewczyk
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to
 * deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the
 * rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or
 * sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS
 * IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define PERLINE 30
#define BUFSIZE 1024

static const char hexrange[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
char buf[BUFSIZE];
int lineidx,line,i,bytes;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    FILE * in, * out;
    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s infile outfile symbol\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    in = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    out = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
    if (!in || !out) {
        fputs("Could not open one of input files.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(out, "/* Generated by HexExport (by Krzysztof Szewczyk a.k.a. Palaiologos) */\n\n");
    fprintf(out, "static const unsigned char %s[] = {", argv[3]);
    while ((bytes = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), in)) > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < bytes; ++i) {
            int byte = ((uint8_t *)buf) [i];
            if (lineidx++ == 0) {
                if (line++)
                    fputc(',', out);
                fputs("\n\t", out);
            } else
                fputs(", ", out);
            fputs("0x", out);
            fputc(hexrange[byte >> 4], out);
            fputc(hexrange[byte & 0xF], out);
            if (lineidx >= PERLINE)
                lineidx = 0;
        }
    }
    fputs("\n};\n", out);
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

What it does, simply, is to generate hex array from file. You can modify it to accomplish your task. Generating such array using macro is either impossible or very hard task. Source code taken from [this place](https://github.com/KrzysztofSzewczyk/HexExport)

Comment: Your file comment says `Copyright (c) 2018 Krzysztof "Palaiologos" Szewczyk` but you say it can be modified (used). I don't see what it has to do with the question.

Comment: It's simple MIT license.
I have implemented such software, and OP can modify it to fit his needs, because these two programs I have mentioned have many things in common

Comment: Before I have pointed out that implementing this using macros has no sense, and it's better to do it in compile time.